# What safety measures should I take during a high voltage test?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, safety, testing

I am planning to do a test with 800 V DC system in the lab. I have taken the high voltage safety training but it's my first time working with high voltage so I want to make sure that I am taking all the high voltage safety measures while working in the lab. Could you please recommend some safety measures?

The things which are in my mind is using a safety transformer for isolation between HV and LV and putting PCB under test in an encapsulated box. Is there is anything else I can do? Also I am unable to find good box online. Can you recommend something?

Comment: Mechanical barrier between you and the DUT, with interlock. If you have any capacitor in the system, assume it's fully charged until proven otherwise by measurement. One hand in your pocket is nice to not have a shock though your heart, but my old professor taught us something even better - two hands in pocket as in do your entire setup to be automated so you don't need to manually intervene what so ever.

Comment: Don't touch the shiny! I mean: Don't touch the shiny! Do your setup, leave and apply power. Do your measurements via remote instruments (GPIB,Ethernet...), then remove power and: Don't touch the shiny! (Capacitors). Before you change your setup make sure the DUT has no voltage left (Measure, not assume!). Look thorugh your schematics before hand: Where are capacitors?

Comment: I am not going to work with live circut. Since it is double pulse test, so I just wanted to establish my test setup with probes connected at all testing points with ossiloscopre and then supplying HV, making the measurement and turning it off to analyse the results later on